# FabricJs Multiple Canvases Load Same Image Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a loop from 1-2, inside the loop I created 2 canvases on the screen and store them in an object and then load in the same 2 images on each canvas, but the images are only appearing on the last canvas. Why is it not loading on both canvases? There is also a text object which works on both canvases in the same loop.

Example code, it literally is just adding the images to the second canvas on the screen and ignoring the first, but the text object is added to both?

```
var canvases = {};
var imageUrls = ['url here','url 2 here'];
for(var p = 1; p <= 2; p++){
    canvases[p] = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-element-'+p);
    var t = new fabric.Text('Testing',{top:600,left:0});
    canvases[p].add(t);
    canvases[p].renderAll();
    for(var i in imageUrls){
        fabric.Image.fromUrl(imageUrls[i],function(img){
            img.set({
                width:500,
                height:500,
                top:0,
                left:0
            });
            canvases[p].add(img);
            canvases[p].renderAll();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `imageUrls` array contains images at 0 and 1 position you are accessing at 1 and 2.
2. `fabric.Image.fromUrl` function name is `fabric.Image.fromURL`
3. As it is a loading image is async function you need to keep in a self invoking function or simply use `let` in for loop `for (let p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {`

```js
var canvases = {};
var imageUrls = ['', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=canvas1', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=canvas2'];
for (var p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {
  canvases[p] = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-element-' + p);
  var t = new fabric.Text('Testing', {
    top: 600,
    left: 0
  });
  canvases[p].add(t);
  canvases[p].renderAll();
  (function(index) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrls[p], function(img) {
      img.set({
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      });
      canvases[index].add(img);
      canvases[index].renderAll();
    });
  })(p);
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border :2px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas-element-1' width=300 height=300></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas-element-2' width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: brilliant thanks, I didn't realise load from url was async , my bad. And the loop you mentioned 1 and 3, I know this one, the code is a snippet from a wider bit of code so you can ignore that loop it's not relevant. Thanks for the answer.